# How do i designate in XSD that an element only contains CDATA?

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I represent the following in XSD.

```
<price-update>
    <![CDATA[
      arbitrary data goes here
    ]]>
</price-update>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're using CDATA? In other words, might it be possible to pass that information in an element (or multiple elements) that you could add to your schema definition?

Comment: The consumer of my doc also needs some more info which is defined in its own XML language. We don't want to use separate files. What i want to do is piggyback another XML doc inside mine.

Comment: You can't.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392770/force-use-of-cdata-in-xml-schema

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<element name="price-update" type="string"></element>
```

is about as close as you can get.

(I thought it best to move the answer out of the comments and into an actual answer).

Answer (score 27):

A CDATA tag is merely a means of escaping data as a text node.  Therefore you cannot stipulate that you require a CDATA node.

From a DOM perspective, the following documents are identical:

```
<doc>value</doc>
```

and

```
<doc><![CDATA[value]]></doc>
```

Comment: SO how would you recommend that i writ ethe XSD?

Like this?

<element name="price-update" type="string"></element>

Comment: I think type="string" is about as close as you can get.

Comment: You might consider defining your own type using a regex pattern, but I don't think that would work as the XSD processing doesn't "see" the CDATA part actually apply the pattern (not definite though).