# Force use of CDATA in XML-schema

Tags: xml, xsd, cdata

I am creating an xml schema, and I want to make sure that the values in all the elements
are CDATA elements.

Is there a way to force this using XML-schema?

Comment: CDATA is just a convenient way of encapsulating text.  You should care if it's text with entity escaping or CDATA should you?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm using this schema as a mean of synchronizing between several co-workers that may inflict changes on certain XML files. Our standard is for XML values to be surrounded by CDATA and I would like to use the XML-schema to enforce this standard.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Not as such.  What's the purpose of this standard?

Comment: To force machine generated xmls to use cdata. If machine generated xmls are plain (no cdata), they may be correct at first uses, but later fail, when the data incorporates conflicting characters. So I would like to enforce the cdata block from the very beginning, to catch programmers' errors immediately and avoid possible problems in the future. Bad idea?

Comment: A good reason for wanting something like this is to enforce at the schema level that whitespace is important in a value.  Having this done in a schema would mean tools that do object serialization based on the schema would know to always put a CDATA block there so if a human later edits the file they don't mess up formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i designate in XSD that an element only contains CDATA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175695/how-do-i-designate-in-xsd-that-an-element-only-contains-cdata)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I recall XML Schema works on the XML Infoset, meaning with the XML document after it is parsed, entities are resolved, whitespace is normalised and CDATA is processed. CDATA is a way of easing the textual serialization not a part of the structural model. So: No. Neither in DTDs or RELAX NG.