# How to force an element to contain only CDATA through XSD

Tags: xsd

My requirement is that any Xml file that will be validated against my schema should conform to following condition.

The OTHERWISE element can contain only CDATA section and nothing else.

Example

Valid XML: `<OTHERWISE ContentURI=""><![CDATA[<html>Good-bye</html>]]></OTHERWISE>`

Invalid XML: `<OTHERWISE ContentURI="">ABC</OTHERWISE>`

I am trying the following:

`<xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:restriction base="OtherwiseAtt">
        <xs:pattern value="^&lt;\!\[CDATA\[[a-zA-Z0-9]*\]\]&gt;" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleContent>`

Any thing can go inside the CDATA. I have put [a-zA-Z0-9]* just for testing purpose.

Please help me out.

Thanks
Sabri

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Why should you care if the document uses CDATA or escaping?

Comment: Very similiar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793575/how-to-restrict-an-element-to-be-non-empty-through-xsd

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force use of CDATA in XML-schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392770/force-use-of-cdata-in-xml-schema)

Answer (score 3):

The content between `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` is handled by the parser. Your XML file has been fully parsed by the time that it is validated. CDATA is basically another way to escape special characters. The validator will not have a way to determine if an element contains CDATA or not in the way that you wish.

The purpose of validation is to place controls on the structure of your documents. It is not and cannot enforce a particular method of escaping text.

Why would you need to require that the content is escaped by CDATA? This sounds like an attempt to handle a poor design choice at an earlier stage.

Comment: What I understood from your answer is by the time the XML file is validated against the schema the CDATA section is already replaced by the text inside the CDATA and it totally makes sense to me.

Comment: As you said "The validator will not have a way to determine if an element contains CDATA or not in the way that you wish", so is there any other way to do it?

Comment: And if not then can we force an element not to be empty? It must contain some innertext which is not a child element again.

Comment: @Saurabh, CDATA doesn't have anything to do with emptiness. Briefly, there is no sensible way to determine if an XML element contains CDATA or not and you shouldn't need to - conceptually, escaped PCDATA and CDATA are the same. However, if you want to ensure that the element contains only text and is not empty, then you should probably ask another question