# How to restrict an element to be non-empty through xsd

Tags: xsd

I need to restrict the elements in xml file to be non empty using xsd files. Can I force the elements to contain only CDATA sections?

Comment: You already asked this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781895/how-to-force-an-element-to-contain-only-cdata-through-xsd

Answer (score 0):

The only tool you have is the xs:string pattern restriction as in below.  CDATA is just an alternative to escaping with entity references. You should use entity references in your pattern.

```
<simpleType name="NewType2">
    <restriction base="string">
        <minLength value="5"></minLength>
        <maxLength value="30"></maxLength>
        <pattern value="(&lt;html&gt;).*(&lt;/html&gt;)"></pattern>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Comment: Note that I'm not great with Regular Expressions, I am not confident that this will correctly evaluate anything. Also note that you should be indifferent on whether the clients you are inter-operating with choose to escape with entity ref's or with CDATA.