# Why must a type=html gadget include a CDATA section?

Tags: google-gadget

[Google Gadgets](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/fundamentals.html#Content_Type):

> The rules for a type="html" gadget are as follows:
>   A type="html" gadget **must** include a CDATA section, and any HTML must go within that section:

I don't quite understand why must a gadget include a CDATA section.

[From what I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392770/force-use-of-cdata-in-xml-schema), an XML Schema is never able to ensure that an element has a CDATA section,

So why must we include a CDATA section within the element? What's wrong with manually escaping it?

Answer (score 0):

CDATA is a standard way of doing it and it generally makes life easier for everyone, not having to escape the HTML, etc. Google are free to set any rules they please with regards to this and using CDATA is probably what is easiest for them.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I don't get it. It's XMl, and Using a CDATA or not in an XML document has no difference..

Comment: Yeah, but Google can make their own decisions about what they do and do not want in their requests. Their spec says that it must be in CDATA.