# What code should I add in xsd so that code could generates CDATA tag automatically in xml?

Tags: xml, xsd, cdata

What code should I add in xsd so that it generates CDATA tag automatically in xml?

For Eg: in XSD

```
<xsd:element name="any">
//code to generates CDATA tag automatically in xml 
</xsd:element>
```

in xml test case it should auto generates and show like

```
  <any>
       <![CDATA[
            <xml tags>abc</xml tags>
     ]]>
</any>
```

I want this because under any tag, I would get another XML and I need to treat that whole XML as string without any Java code. So I am looking for solution in XSD only.

Comment: XSD or XSL/XSLT?

Comment: XSD..file as i mentioned in my subject dear Lucero. please assist

Comment: It's not clear what the "it" in your question is. You're presumably using some software tool that generates XML based on what it sees in the XSD, and we need to know what tool that is. (But I suspect the answer is that it can't be done.)

Comment: volante tool i am using, but i am asking for a trick which i can apply in xsd only to get CDATA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i designate in XSD that an element only contains CDATA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175695/how-do-i-designate-in-xsd-that-an-element-only-contains-cdata)